# ui-router require in multiple sibling views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

## How it is

I'm working on an application which has a little but more complex form than usual. I've splitted it up by having different views and controllers, but still keeping them inside a form element.

It has different sections but the payload of the request should contains all the information when I do the POST request. So basically that's why it has one main form (well it's not about having it inside a form or not, I could even have it without a form and then collecting models and submitting it by including all model's data into one main).

## Question

My question is:

- Does ui-router has a kind of `required` field to set? Just in order to have the required controller's functions and scope.
- Does anyone knows a better solution?

## Code

The code is just an example, this is not literally the code I have.

#### View (sectionMain.html)

```
<form>
    <div ui-view="section1"></div>
    <div ui-view="section2"></div>
    <div ui-view="section3"></div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### State definition

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
        url: '/mstate',
        parent: 'stateForAuthenticatedUsers',
        views: {
            //this will be loaded what I have above. Just a part of the page.
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/myModule/views/sectionMain.html',
                controller: 'Section1Ctrl as vm'
            },
            'section1@myState': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/myModule/views/section1.html',
                controller: 'Section1Ctrl as vmState1'
            },
            'section2@myState': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/myModule/views/section2.html',
                controller: 'Section2Ctrl as vmState2'
            },
            'section3@myState': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/myModule/views/section3.html',
                controller: 'Section3Ctrl as vmState3'
            },
        }
    });
```

#### Controller (for example State2Ctrl)

```
function State2Ctrl($scope) {
    //stuffs here. Need to refer parent's scope somehow
    $scope.vm.someVariableOrObject
}
```

## My concern

My only concern is that trusting a value `vm` which has been defined in the state's configuration doesn't give me the feeling that it's a well composed structure. I'd really need something I can require to, to have it explicitly instead of blindly trusting in a value `vm`.
Also my views contains the `vm.someVariable` in order to refer the parent's scope. But I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use your `$rootScope`? An easy way to achieve what you are looking for, without passing in a `$scope` every time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think it's a bad practice to pollute `$rootScope`. Also it doesn't give me the explicit `required` thing that I need.

Comment: And what about using global `values`?

Comment: it's the same story. :P